# how to split a text file and modify it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, text-files

I currently have a text file that reads like this:

```
101, Liberia, Monrovia, 111000, 3200000, Africa, English, Liberia Dollar;
102, Uganda, Kampala, 236000, 34000000, Africa, English and Swahili, Ugandan Shilling;
103, Madagascar, Antananarivo, 587000, 21000000, Africa, Magalasy and Frances, Malagasy Ariary;
```

I'm currently printing the file using this code:

```
with open ("base.txt",'r') as f:
   for line in f:
      words = line.split(';')
      for word in words:
         print (word)
```

What I would like to know is, how can I modify a line by using their id number (101 for example) and keep the format they have and add or remove lines based on their id number?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by an line. Do you mean a line of the file, or a list element after you used split()?

Comment: A list element after the split() and then changing or adding text to those lists

Comment: Did you mean `line.split(',')`? From the file you gave spliting the lines by `;` wouldn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding your asking how to modify a word in a line and then insert the modified line back into the file.

### Change a word in the file

```
def change_value(new_value, line_number, column):
    with open("base.txt",'r+') as f: #r+ means we can read and write to the file
        lines = f.read().split('\n') #lines is now a list of all the lines in the file
        words = lines[line_number].split(',')
        words[column] = new_value
        lines[line_number] = ','.join(words).rstrip('\n') #inserts the line into lines where each word is seperated by a ','
        f.seek(0)
        f.write('\n'.join(lines)) #writes our new lines back into the file
```

In order to use this function to set `line 3, word 2` to `Not_Madasgascar` call it like this:

```
change_word("Not_Madagascar", 2, 1)
```

You will always have to add `1` to the line/word number because the first line/word is `0`

### Add a new line to the file

```
def add_line(words, line_number):
    with open("base.txt",'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines.insert(line_number, ','.join(words) + '\n')
        f.seek(0)
        f.writelines(lines)
```

In order to use this function add a line at the end containing the words `this` `line` `is` `at` `the` `end` call it like this:

```
add_line(['this','line','is','at','the','end'], 4) #4 is the line number
```

For more information on opening files see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

For more information on reading from and modifying files see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm fairly new to all of this, how would I go using the function [change_word]

Comment: @Nandito104 No worries! Everyone's a beginner at some point. I will change my post will more details on using it.

Comment: @Nandito104 It's changed.

Comment: in case i wanted to add another line, how would i go about that, based on the function you gave me?

Comment: Don't you need to *seek* to file start after read? Frankly, with that approach it would have been better to open the file first in read mode, and then re-open it in write mode. Besides, changing in place is risky business - it is not justified unless you change a definite fragment with a fragment of the same size. And in that case, binary mode is advised

Comment: @Nandito104 Add another line where?

Comment: At the end of the text file

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) is a strong tool for solving your requirements. It provides the tools for easily working with CSV files. You can manage your data in `DataFrames`.

```
import pandas as pd

# read the CSV file into DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', header=None, index_col = 0)
print (df)
```

[image]

```
# eliminating the `;` character
df[7] = df[7].map(lambda x: str(x).rstrip(';'))
print (df)
```

[image]

```
# eliminating the #101 row of data
df.drop(101, axis=0, inplace=True)
print (df)
```

[image]

Comment: A csv editor sounds like a good fit, but you may want to provide some more explanation of what your commands do.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this file into an `OrderedDict` would probably be helpful if you are trying to preserve the original file ordering as well as have the ability to references lines in the file for modification/addition/deletion.  There are quite a few assumptions about the full format of the file in the following example, but it will work for your test case:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

content = OrderedDict()

with open('base.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            print line
            words = line.split(',')  # Assuming that you meant ',' vs ';' to split the line into words
            content[int(words[0])] = ','.join(words[1:])

print(content[101])  # Prints " Liberia, Monrovia, etc"...

content.pop(101, None)  # Remove line w/ 101 as the "id"
```